# Limit tag selection to predefined list

Tags: tags, limit

It can get really messy when I'm entering tags. Sometimes I enter `tag 1` sometimes `Tag1` or `tag01`, this is very messy and I can get a lot of duplicated tags that should be the same thing.

Is it possible to limit tag selection to only predefined ones and make action of adding new tags more "explicit"?

Right now, I can add new tags just by pressing "enter" with new keyword in the search box.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You will certainly receive many answers. This question is very good.

We are speaking about the tags when you try to type them for a new post, for instance in the Dashboard.

When you type the tags, you get the proposals. I think this is a good feedback.

However, it could be possible to create even the better algorithm how the tags will pop up. Right now the tags will pop up based on the first letters you type.

So you can catch you eye on these proposals. This may be all you need.